# Copy-paste specific columns from rows if an If condition is satisfied

Tags: excel, loops, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to build a macro to copy paste specific columns from rows, when an If condition is satisfied. The part of the If condition is tested and working, as I have used it in another macro. The problem in my case is that I dont know how to select specific columns of a row inside a loop. I only know how to select the entire row (in this case it would have been rows(i).EntireRow.Copy if I am not mistaken). I am providing my code below. The part that needs editing is the

```
.Rows(i).Columns(1, 4, 6, 8).Copy
Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").range("W2").Paste
```

The entire code is this one

(UPDATED VERSION)

I am providing the screenshots too

[image]
[image]

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As range
Dim mDiff1 As Double
mDiff1 = 0.01
With Worksheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT")
    lr = range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
        If Cells(i, "U").Value - Cells(i, "V").Value > mDiff1 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .range("L" & i & ":V" & i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .range("L" & i & ":V" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Copy
    Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").range("AI2").PasteSpecial
End With
```

Comment: Try this: `.Range("A" & i & ", D" & i & ", F" & i & ", H" & i & "").Copy`

Comment: Well, the paste method wont work.. I need the paste to be performed on the columns W to AF from row 2 and down

Comment: You need to use `.Range("W" & i).PasteSpecial(xlValues)`

Comment: Thanks buddy! helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy you may use

```
Range("A" & i & ", D" & i & ", F" & i & ", H" & i & "").Copy  '(as mentioned in comment)
```

or

```
Union(.Range("A" & i), .Range("D" & i), .Range("F" & i), .Range("H" & i)).Copy
```

---

Thus, try

```
Union(.Range("A" & i), .Range("D" & i), .Range("F" & i), .Range("H" & i)).Copy
Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").range("W2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or just

```
Union(.Range("A" & i), .Range("D" & i), .Range("F" & i), .Range("H" & i)).Copy
Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").range("W2").PasteSpecial
```

or

```
Union(.Range("A" & i), .Range("D" & i), .Range("F" & i), .Range("H" & i)).Copy Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").range("W2")
```

---

***EDIT :***

Is there any specific reason why you are looping from bottom to up, if not change `FOR` loop as

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
```

Your code will be

```
Dim mDiff As Integer
Dim rng As Range
mDiff = 0.03
With Worksheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT")
    lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, "U").Value - Cells(i, "V").Value > mDiff Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Range("L" & i & ":V" & i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Range("L" & i & ":V" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Copy
    Sheets("WFRandVFR_REPORT").Range("AI2").PasteSpecial
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the 3rd one!

Comment: I hadnt noticed it but it overwrites the data... So, it works but it doesnt paste the data one below the other... sorry.. I just checked it. I thought it simply had one line in the beginning!

Comment: it works now, but it is pasting every row that the difference is>0.. So, it does not recognize the mdiff but simply pastes all of the rows for which Cells(i, "U").Value - Cells(i, "V").Value > 0.  To be honest U and V column have percentages.. could this possibly be the reason?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - May be declare `mDiff` as `Double` using `Dim mDiff As Double`.

Comment: just did that but still remains the same. It copy pastes everything >0... Also, when I put as mDiff1 a value like mDiff1=0.9 it says Error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set, while without changinf the code at all , If i put mDiff1=0.01 it works..

Comment: ok I think I fixed it.. I changed in lrow EndxlUp with EndxlDown... However tha cde became A LOT slower